# Store a signature image in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

As a part of a PDF signing system solution it is required to capture and store the signature image in a data store.I was thinking of recommending the LDAP user object jpegPhoto to store the signature jpeg file (encryption can be applied).Rather than a database since then the question is who would take ownership of the database (IT-POLICY-DEPT thinge).The AD is already owned and secure (assuming).So it would be a matter of the admins give access on SELF or appropriate permission to update  to user object for a period and then once the signatures are stored then later only retrieval permission given.I am not a system admin and we are just taking about 100 users,it this a big job ? The admins are just brushing off the suggestion without giving any proper explanation ! Can some give the pros and cons if any ....:-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but I won't recommend modifying AD schema unless you really know what you are doing. You create a mess of your site forest and recovery may not be easy even if possible. That said, also consider the burden that will be placed on replication (if you have multiple DCs).

[Add Photos in Active Directory](http://www.arricc.net/active-directory-photos-sharepoint.php)

Comment: I don't want to modify the ad schema, I will use jpegPhoto attribute of user object.

Answer (score 1):

A con would be that this attribute may be used in other applications like Outlook to show the user's photo.

I do agree though that not changing the AD Schema would make the solution easier to accept by the sysadmins. Maybe you can look for another attribute to store your data in?

Also I think that the user may be allowed to write to this attribute by default.

Answer (score 1):

Our requirements and solution are different but we did use jpegPhoto, we store a photo of the user in the thumbnailPhoto attribute and their signature in the jpegPhoto attribute. Our admin imported the images using a program called AD Photos, this then resized the images before importing into them into AD. We sent everyone an email and asked them to print it off and sign it in the box provided, we then loaded all the papers into a sheet fed scanner and captured just the signature. The images were all small >10k grey scale and we've seen no complaints from Active Directory (300 users).